# Create Role-Based Authorization with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application where I want to add role-based authentication.  I'm using Windows Authentication because it's an intranet app.  I already have a custom database that contains the users/roles that frankly doesn't map to the fields in the IdentityFramework.  I can easily get the logged-in user's name via the Context.User.Identity.Name.  I then want to look up the user in the custom user/roles table in order to get the available roles for that user.  Then I want to use an annotation-based authentication filter decorated at the Controller or Action method level.  For example, [Authorize(roles="admin")].

I was able to get this working by turning off Windows Authentication and using Forms Authentication with Cookies.  In the AccountController I ran code like this:

```csharp
using (LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password))
{
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginModel.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
    };
    ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new ClaimsPrincipal(principal),
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(200)
        });
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

I would then store the claims in a cookie.  Then when I decorate the Controller with [Authorize(roles="admin")], I'm able to retrieve the View without issues.  The authorization works.  I would like to replicate this same functionality for WindowsAuthentication without logging the user in.  I have tried using a ClaimsTransformer and implementing Policy-based authorization, which works.  But if I decorate it with [Authorize(roles="admin")] it bombs when I navigate to the action method.  Here is the ClaimsTransformer:

```csharp
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, identity.Name),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
    };
    identity.AddClaims(claims);
    return Task.FromResult(principal);
}
```

What piece am I missing in order to use the [Authorize(Roles="admin")] working? BTW, I'm currently using ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit of a late answer, but I've been troubleshooting the same issue today and none of the answers I've seen on similar posts have fixed my issue.

Here are the steps I took to be able to use [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] on my controller with Windows authentication.

1. Double check that `UseAuthentication()` comes before `UseAuthorization()` in the `Configure()` method of Startup.cs

```csharp
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication(); // <--- this needs to be before
    app.UseAuthorization(); // <----this

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Hccc}/{action=Index}/");
    });
}
```

2. Have a claims transformer to handle the necessary roles. For example,

```csharp
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
    var user = UserAuth.GetUserRole(ci.Name); // gets my user from db with role
    // handle your roles however you need.
    foreach (var role in user.Roles)
    {
        var roleClaim = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, role.RoleName);
        ci.AddClaim(roleClaim);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(principal);
}
```

3. Set up the `ConfigureServices()` method in Startup.cs to handle authorization

```csharp
services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
// Implement a policy called "AdminOnly" that uses "Windows" authentication
// The policy requires Role "Admin"
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Windows");
        policy.RequireRole("Admin");
    });
});
services.AddMvc();
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

4. Use the `[Authorize]` tag to implement the policy. For my case, I wanted to block access to a controller unless the user was an "Admin".

```csharp
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write a custom Policy Authorization handlers in which you get all User's Roles and check if they contains your desired role name.

Refer to following steps:

1. Create CheckUserRoleRequirement(accept a parameter)

```csharp
public class CheckUserRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string RoleName { get; private set; }

    public CheckUserRoleRequirement(string roleName)
    {
        RoleName = roleName;
    }
}
```

2. Create CheckUserRoleHandler

```csharp
public class CheckUserRoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CheckUserRoleRequirement>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CheckUserRoleHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        CheckUserRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var name = context.User.Identity.Name;
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();

            //your logic to look up the user in the custom user/roles table in order to get the available roles for that user
            List<string> roles = dbContext.UserRoles.Where(...;
            if (roles != null && roles.Contains(requirement.RoleName))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

3. Register Handler in ConfigureServices

```csharp
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminRole", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new CheckUserRoleRequirement("Admin")));
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CheckUserRoleHandler>();
```

4. Usage

```csharp
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminRole")]
```

Comment: So another words, I don't need to fool with Claims? Also, what I would like to accomplish is not having to hit the database or dbcontext EVERY TIME I am requesting an action method with an authorize roles attribute.  Once the user is authenticated once, I'd like to cache this information.  The forms authentication allows you to tie this to a cookie with an expiration.