# ASP.NET core how to use Authentication only for specific routes?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, single-page-application

I configured to use windows authentication for my asp.net react app.

on ConfigureServices() method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

then on configure() method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

However, by doing so, all requests will trigger the authentication process.
I actually only want my api routes (in `/api/my/resource` ) to be secure using windows authentication, and want to let the whole react resource folder to be public (in `/any/path/here`).

How do I configure to use windows authentication only for route starting with `/api`.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried Authorize & AllowAnonymous attributes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You can implement Role-Based Authorization Or Policy-Based Authorization with Windows Authentication, then in the API controller, use the Authorize attribute to apply the policy to the controller. Refer to the following links: [ASP.NET Core - Authorization Using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524466/) and [Create Role-Based Authorization with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105635/).

Comment: Thanks, guys. I came up with a way to do it, it is very simple actually. Please see my answer. @ZhiLv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776177/214977

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved that by just doing this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // don't use default policy
    // options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Then add `[Authorize]` to the controllers that need authentication.

```
[Authorize]     // trigger authentication process
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase {}
```

Then I can choose specific routes to require authentication.