# How to make Windows Authentication with specific users and roles that can access the application? (ASP.NET CORE MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an intranet application with Windows Authentication. And I want to have a database table that contains the allowed users that can access the application.

I want to get the username after someone try to log into (successfully, thinking about the user existence into domain), to check if it is present into database to allow the access, besides that, redirect to a static HTML saying he can't access the application.
How can I achieve something like that?

And about the [Authorize], User Roles that ASP.NET Identity provides can be used in Windows Authentication mode to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @Dreidel, have your checked this doc:https://gist.github.com/DamienBraillard/4dbd6aa2c56edf5a8e57c59b6e08da94

Comment: @Rena this refers to Roles mainly, right? But I can't find anything about the main problem that is handle user login and check if it's existence in a database table.

Comment: Hi @Dreidel, I got it. Combine with Identity database, pls refer to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/60108561/11398810

Comment: Hi @Rena. Thanks again, but I think I'm too newbie to this subject about Authorization and Authentication. In my case, I think I will not use Identity because my table just have the username column, and more...
But I think the way I'm wondering that I can reach my desired result (execute some code after the user has Authenticated (after fill the username and password of the windows authentication pop up), to then check if the user exists in my table).

I will try studying more but still get nothing working

Comment: At least your references makes me discover more useful things. Appreciate.